# Remove all html tags except <img> or <img/> tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I have a JS string and I would like to prevent html and js injection on my website message input.

How can I remove all HTML tags from a string except the img tag, because it is used to display emoticons like this:

```
<img class="emo" src="images/emo/smile.png">
```

I am using the following code to remove all html tags but it only works for the `<br>` tag and not img tag.

```
function remove_tags(html)
 {
   var html = html.replace("<img>","||img||");  
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   html = tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
   return html.replace("||img||","<img>");  
 }
```

Either remove those html tags or simply display them as simple texts like:
`<script> alert("hi");</script>`

but except the `<img>` tags.

Comment: please make search on google for regexp in javascript

Comment: Bad news: you can still inject scripts with image tags!

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this using jQuery:

```
function remove_tags(html)
 {
   var html = html.replace("<img>","||img||");  
   var text = jQuery(html).text();
   return text.replace("||img||","<img>");  
 }
```

Reference : [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: It's worth noting that executing `jQuery` here will actually run the contents of `html`!  Try it with `<img src=x onerror=alert("Test")>`

Comment: I tried it, this is not working for me.. it does not print anything at all. not even plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code

```
var html = '<img class="emo" src="images/emo/smile.png">';
var text = html.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
```

`replace` method remove all html tags in string.

You can test every html string in bottom demo.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    var html = $("textarea").val();
    var text = html.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
    $("textarea").val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea><img src=x onerror=alert("Test") /><p>aa</p></textarea>
<br />
<button>Remove HTML tags</button>
```